# Working with directshow in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, directshow

I have an MFC project, and I'm trying to use DirectShow.

However, when I build my project, I have the following linker errors

```
MFC_ATMApplicationDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IGraphBuilder
MFC_ATMApplicationDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2
MFC_ATMApplicationDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2
MFC_ATMApplicationDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_FilterGraph
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1):

You fix this the same way you fix linker errors: you add missing library:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
```

e.g. the way it is done [here](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/PlayMp3File/PlayMp3File.cpp?rev=133#L12), or alternatively you can add the same dependency using Project Settings window.

Comment: I already added that but I still have the same problem, I fixed this, strangely enough, when I include DirectShow code in non-MFC classes, the issue disappears